# Managing memory warnings in IOS. Any pointers?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, memory-management

in my app, sometimes I get a level 1 memory warning which I think is acceptable given the amount of work it is doing. When that happens, it calls the viewdidunload for one of the views which is part of the tabbarviewcontroller. In the viewdidunload, i set the outlets to nil which I think is totally normal.

The issue arises if I try to access that class again. Since it was deallocated, it will throw a bad access error which prevents me from showing that view again. If I don't set those outlets to nil then it won't crash which is normal but the convention is always to set any outlets to nul in the viewdidunload.

Any pointers for handling memory warnings in this case? I don't want to delete the code i have in the viewdidunload method since it is going against the convention.

I forgot to add that i subclassed the tabbarcontroller >_<

Answer (score 1):

In that case, again the subviews added to xib file will be allocated when you load that view again. And if you want to customize something, do that in `viewDidLoad` method.

Comment: Basically the viewdidload doesn't even get called again. Once it thetbbarcontroller calls setindex, it says the controller is not ther and it crashes.

Answer (score 1):

Where do the views which were deallocate get allocated?  It sounds like you are deallocating a view in `viewDidUnload` that was not allocate in, for example, `viewDidLoad`. Instead it might have been created somewhere else, so it does not get recreated then the viewController's view is reloaded.

Comment: It is all created in the iB so am not releasing anything in the viewdidunload. I am only setting to nil in the viewdidunload. I think the issue arrises due to the fact that i am using a custom tab bar which doesn't cater for released viewcontrollers. I will add a check there to reload the viewcontroller.

Comment: Ah, did you subclass UITabBarController?

Comment: Ye I subclassed the tabbarcontroller

Comment: My guess is that it would usually reload it for me but since i subclassed it i probably removed some of the memory management stuff such as reloading the viewcontroller if it is unloaded.

Comment: Things are a little trickier then.  Apple says in its documentation "This class is not intended for subclassing." So I think you are safer *not* doing anything in viewDidUnload.  Just pass the message to [super viewDidUnload] and let the UITabBarController manage its view controllers the way that it is expecting to.  Your best bet is doing as little as you possibly can inside the subclass...or maybe even consider if there is an alternative way of doing what you want without an explicit subclass.

Comment: Hmm yes we are not supposed to subclass it but it is very custom . Maybe I can try to reload the viewcontroller just before setting the selected index.